# Mysql Left Join with WHEN clause, WHERE and CONCATE

Tags: mysql, left-join, where-clause, concatenation

I am trying to solve one mysql query. I have **TWO Databases** e.g. A and B.
Database A has table ABC and Database B has table XYZ.

Joining condition phoneno from ABC = phoneno or cellphone from XYZ.

ABC Table

[image]

XYZ Table

[image]

Required Output

[image]

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS/product & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular-formatted base table initialization. PS Use language to say how output is a function of input. Don't hope we'll guess. Show parts you can do.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
a.mId AS mId,
CASE WHEN (a.pId = 0 OR a.pId IS NULL) 
     THEN x.id 
     ELSE a.pId 
     END AS pId,
CASE WHEN (x.firstname IS NOT NULL) 
     THEN CONCAT(x.firstname, ' ', x.lastname) 
     ELSE a.pName 
     END as pName,
a.phoneno as phoneno
FROM ABC a
LEFT JOIN XYZ x ON a.phoneno = COALESCE(x.phoneno, x.cellphone);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am only interested in rows from table `B.XYZ` supplying missing values for rows in table `A.ABC` for which column `pid = 0`. So:

```
select t1.mid,
       t1.pid,
       if(t2.id is null, t1.pName, concat_ws(' ', t2.firstname, t2.lastname)) as pName,
       t1.phoneno
from A.ABC t1 left join B.XYZ t2 on t1.pid = 0 and t1.phoneno in (t2.phoneno, t2.cellphone)
;
```

Comment: You started if condition but where should I add closing brackets?

Comment: I am not sure I follow your question. I was missing a ')', which I have added.